# Shipment cost page in virtuemart

Tags: virtuemart

My template of shiping cost page is:

```
<span class="vmshipment"><span class="vmshipment_name">Kurier K-EX</span><span class="vmshipment_description">paczka do 30kg</span><span class="vmshipment_cost"> (-15,00 zł)</span></span>
```

It appears like that:

**Kurier K-EXpaczka do 30kg (-15,00 zł)**

I want it to appear like that:

**Kurier K-EXpaczka do 30kg -15,00 zł**

without ()

I can't find it in select_shipment.php file. Where should I look for it?

Answer (score 0):

**FOUND IT:**

in administrator/components/com_virtuemart/plugins/vmpsplugin.php
change:

```
$costDisplay = '<span class="' . $this->_type . '_cost"> (' . JText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_PLUGIN_COST_DISPLAY') . $costDisplay . ")</span>";
```

to

```
$costDisplay = '<span class="' . $this->_type . '_cost"> ' . JText::_ ('COM_VIRTUEMART_PLUGIN_COST_DISPLAY') . $costDisplay . "</span>";
```